# Quantum entanglement continuous measurement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, quantum-entanglement

Is there a possibility (if not real than at least theoretical) that we could measure the spin of an electron continously over some (even very short) period of time, so that it does not change during the measurement?

I'm thinking maybe of something like observing it continuously...
Is it achievable?

Comment: Er, something like this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Zeno_effect

Comment: You can measure quantum systems continuously (or piece by piece), acquiring only a small amount of information about the state during each time interval. Correspondingly, you will only disturb the state little during each time step. However, the total disturbance will be determined by the total information gain, so there is nothing you will win as compared to an instant measurement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a quantum zero type measurement if the spin of that particle has a well defined single particle spin state and you zeno it to stay in that state.

But this would require that it not have its spin entangled with any other particle (in order to have the well defined single particle spin state).

Comment: The Zeno effect allows to freeze a spin in a *known* state, so it is not a continuous measurement which allows to acquire information about the initial state of the system.